# Using the word "effort" correctly

Tags: prepositions

Which would be a correct and natural usage of the word, out of the following three choices?

I was trying to save some efforts **on / of / at** hosting two code bases, for a single website.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65234/effort-at-of-in-shooting

Comment: What's obvious there is that "I was trying to save some efforts on / of / at hosting two code bases, for a single website" makes no real sense.

If you’re asking about English or any other “correct and natural usage ” then most simply no, it would not.